# Avoid VIsual Studio Code terminal to change its size when opening a file from it

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the Visual Studio terminal, having it expanded to full size (that is, it occupies the whole editor), if a file is opened by writing `code <name_of_file>`, the file will open and the terminal will be restored to a smaller size.

Is there any way to modify this behavior so, when opening a file, the terminal window either does nothing or it gets completely minimized and the focus is transferred to the new file editor?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating a bit, as [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1DiQfhIUIQ)video explains, a partial solution for the problem above is using `Panel: Opens Maximized`. I say partial because, while that option will make the terminal always open maximized, if a file is opened from it, it will still be restored to a 'medium' size.